# Authorization Code Flow and multiple Tabs

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I need to understand how to avoid or how to manage sticky session during OAuth2 - Authorization Code Flow Grant, in particular during:
GET /uaa/oauth/authorize, POST /uaa/login and again GET /uaa/oauth/authorize

Ours auth service will serve just two webapps, owned by us, each is a resource server with checks for token and validity. If there isn't a token or it isn't valid they will redirect directly to Auth Server login page (true telling to the first call, GET /oauth/authorize).

Authorization Code Flow Grant need the following steps:

-First call to register client request GET /uaa/oauth/authorize, storing on session (Spring Redis in my case) some info, like client's callbackurl

-Second call to login by user credential POST /login

-Third call to obtain ACCESS_CODE GET /uaa/oauth/authorize, retrieving callback url from session.

But what if I fake two requests coming from two different clients, opening on the same browser two different tabs?

For example one with:

```
http://localhost:9191/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client-one&scope=auth&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/client-one
```

and the other with:

```
localhost:9191/uaa/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=client-two&scope=auth&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/client-two
```

Spring Session get messy. For example:

- Opening WebApp1 on Tab1 and then WebApp2 on Tab2.
- Logging on Tab1 will redirect to WebApp2 redirect uri.
- Then logging to Tab2 will return to /uaa/ causing 404.

I've tried to customize SessionRepository without success, but using other services with Oauth2 I'm starting to believe that I'll need at lest for one page in each webapp, proxying before the first call to GET /oauth/authorize.

Is there any best practice suggestion to avoid sticky session with this flow?

Or some way to manage multiple tabs without a html page? Spring-Security use sticky session on default..

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing something like nonce, not supported by spring security by default (as far as I know [Github Spring Security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4442)).

If the user tries to authenticate with a nonce different from the latest one I kick him off to an error page with a message like "login session expired" with a link to the webapp.